# How can I shift a character under a superscript?

Tags: math-mode

I've a math notation, where I want to write comma under the latest character of the superscript. I have following notation `$T^{cpu}$`, where is it possible to write `,` under where `u`?

my code, I was not able to shift `,` one character left:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
$T^{cpu}$,
\end{document}
```

output:

[image]

wanted output, comman is shifted one character left on the normal baseline:

[image]

Comment: You could probably use the AmsTeX command `\pretend{T^{cpu}}\haswidth{desiredwidth}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this? (I updated my answer after learning that `,` (comma) character should be on the baseline and processed in text mode.) Observe that the comma is shifted to the left -- "kerned", in typographic jargon -- by the exact width of the superscript ("scriptstyle") math-mode letter 'u'.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$\scriptstyle u$} % measure width of math-mode 'u'

\begin{document}
$T^{cpu}$\kern-\mylen,
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd simply use `\llap`; the `\scriptspace` will avoid that the comma is completely below the “u”. Also the space factor has to be restored.

I propose `\mathit{cpu}`, because that's likely not the product of three quantities.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\ucomma}{%
  \leavevmode % for safety
  \llap{,}\spacefactor\sfcode`,
  \space
}

\begin{document}

$T^{\mathit{cpu}}$, text

$T^{\mathit{cpu}}$\ucomma text

$T^{cpu}$, text

$T^{cpu}$\ucomma text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This?

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    $T^{cp\underset{'}{u}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to put the comma on the same line as the text, you can use a negative space.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    $T^{cpu}$\hspace{-3pt}, text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the OP wanted a comma on the normal baseline, just cosmetically kerned under the superscript

Answer (score 3):

I understand that the original question did not ask to raise the comma, only to put it so that it is under the last character of the exponent. Werner's answer in the comment (number 2 below) works pretty well. If you want to align it exactly, I guess you can use a right-aligned zero-width box (number 3 below).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $T^{cpu}$,
\item $T^{cpu}\!\!$,
\item $T^{cpu}$\makebox[0pt][r]{,}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The difference between 2 and 3 is rather negligible.

[image: result]